# Javascript: How to clear a non-global (closured) setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, javascript-namespaces

I'm trying to be a good citizen and keep as much out of the global scope as possible. Is there a way to access setTimeout variables that are not in the global scope?

So that, in this example how would someone cancel 'timer'?

```
myObject.timedAction = (function(){
    var timer;
        return function(){
            // do stuff

            // then wait & repeat       
            timer = setTimeout(myObject.timedAction,1000);
        };
})();
```

I've tried `clearTimeout(myObject.timedAction.timer,1000);` (without success), and not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't unless you have a reference to `timer`, which you don't because you're declaring it as a variable in a scope.  You can do something like:

```
myObject.timedAction = (function(){
    return function(){
        // do stuff

        // then wait & repeat       
        myObject.timedAction.timer = setTimeout(myObject.timedAction,1000);
    };
})();

clearTimeout(myObject.timedAction.timer);
```

Note that the above code will only ever allow ONE timer.  If you need references to more than one timer, it needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

The whole point is that the inner variables are private, and inaccessible to the outside world.  SO you have to change your approach a bit:

```
myObject.timedAction = (function(){
    var timer;
    var result = function(){
        // do stuff
        // then wait & repeat       
        timer = setTimeout(myObject.timedAction,1000);
    };

    result.cancel = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    return result;
})();

myObject.timedAction();       // start it
myObject.timedAction.cancel() // end it
```

So now the timer is only ever accessed from inside the closure.  And yes, you can add methods to a function, because JS is awesome.

Comment: Wow, "method" and "function" in the same sentence.

Comment: @TomalakGeretkai remember a function inherits from `Object`. So it's just an object.

Answer (score 1):

Put the timer handle in a property in your object:

```
myObject.timedAction = function(){
  // do stuff
  // then wait & repeat
  this.timer = window.setTimeout(function(){ myObject.timedAction(); },1000);
};
```

Note that you should wrap the call from the timer in a function, so that it's called as a method of your object instead of as a global function, otherwise you won't be able to access your object using `this`.

Now you can stop the timer using:

```
window.clearTimeout(myObject.timer);
```